# Is it safe to allow users to use cron to schedule tasks?

Tags: cron

If a user is granted permission to schedule cron jobs, i.e. by being listed in cron.allow, does this make them any more of a "threat" to the system than a user without that permission?

In my case I am not worried that users are actively malicious - more that a misconfiguration might cause wider problems.

As far as I can tell, the worst they could do is schedule a large number of frequently recurring resource intensive tasks. But as those tasks would run under their user accounts, they would be subject to whatever quotas and limits were in place for that user.

Is that right?

Comment: "safe" is a relative term.

Answer (score 1):

cron jobs can run at "any" time, even when the user is not logged in.  That is mainly a concern with regard to malicious users.  But it certainly does let the user consume more CPU time whether intentionally or not, and for that reason is often prohibited on shared systems.

Answer (score 0):

Together with having no technical reason not to give cron access to users, it is an overkill in my opinion. I generally reserve cron for root and application service admin accounts. If say a developer wants to run something at midnight, I give them `at` access. I really do not want an overzealous programmer to run a query against a software repository, every night to see if there is a new release, while choking network connections and running awk/sed/grep/perl on humongous files, bringing the system down to its knees, hampering legit cron jobs and sometimes fail due to lack of resources.

I do not want to sound like the [BOFH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastard_Operator_From_Hell) but, if you let the users run wild on the system, you really don't know what you are getting yourself into. A lot of them are like children and need to be controlled. If your users are old sysadmins doing some other fiunction, I wouldn't mind giving them a little more freedom, but to a developer, I wouldn't. I have seen how some of these people *develop*. I do not want to do house cleaning after they are done with the system I will be left to deal with.

Comment: if you think doing this makes any difference, you are mistaken.  If you give them `at` you may as well give them access to `cron` (e.g. the last line of the script they run from `at` can be `at 1am tomorrow "$0" "$@"`).  If they can run shell scripts, you may as well give them access to both `at` and `cron` (if it's now 3pm and they want to run their job at 1am, they can `nohup bash -c 'sleep 10h ; /path/to/myscript.sh' &`.  that script could then sleep for 24 hours and run itself again).  or `sleep 36000` if the version of sleep doesn't understand the `h` suffix in `sleep 10h`.

Comment: at needs to be actively babysat. cron usually, gets started with good intentions and forgotten. If someone is that adamant about running a command using `at` every day or night, you can not prevent them from finding a way to do it with long `sleep` periods. My caution was against the casual know-it-all types. Otherwise, I have nothing against people who know their way around the system and aware of the consequences of their actions.